# How is yum atomicity ensured?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, yum

The installers do change a lot of system files. The system may become unbootable if something fails during the software updates. Yet, [it is almost impossible to ensure atomicity of even simple single file write operations.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160115141959/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/adioltean/archive/2005/12/28/507866.aspx) How is all of that is resolved in unix installers? Are they file-system dependent?

Comment: One technique is that files are typically not rewritten but newly created (old versions removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yum relies on rpm to do the transaction ... rpm isn't atomic. history or yum-complete-transaction try to do the best they can, after the fact.

You can also use the LVM snapshot features in recent versions of yum, and then rollback the entire block device if there is a problem. But you have to do the actual rollback using an external bootable LVM environment (because yum/rpm/glibc could all be hosed by that point).

If you need atomic guarantees then you can't directly use rpm directly (Eg. you ostree, 0install, or layering multiple bootable environments).

Comment: I think that this answers my question as I posted it but I would like to see more information. Where did you get all that from?

Answer (score 3):

`yum` 3.2.25 or later brings a *history* command to examine, complete or roll-back transactions.  The history information lives in */var/lib/yum/history*.  The `yum-complete-transaction` tool can be used following a power loss or crash to complete transactions or to simply discard aborted ones by erasing the journaled information maintanined in */var/lib/yum/transaction-all* and */var/lib/yum/transaction-done*.

**UPDATE**

The atomicity is based on a Sqlite database's ability to provide the illusion of atomicity.  An excellent discussion of these technique can be found in a whitepaper entitled [Atomic Commit in SQLite](http://sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html).

Comment: I am also interested to know how reliable is that? How do you ensure that all writes are on the disk and in order, how do you isolate the installation from other processes?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, atomic updates are a problem; yum (and apt, pacman, etc) are not atomic. Fortunately, people are experimenting with solutions. See [rpm-ostree](http://lwn.net/Articles/581811/) and [CoreOS atomic upgrades](http://coreos.com/blog/recoverable-system-upgrades/).